# Scraping Lazada data

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I have used Selenium to get data like item name, price, reviews and so on from the Lazada website. However, it will block me after the first scraping. My question is there any way to solve this? Could you guys give some solution in details. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Lazada having high security, for getting data without blocking you must use proxy. you can even get the data using python request try below code

```
cookies = {
    "user": "en"
    }
req_headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }
proxies = {"https": "http://000.0.0.0:0000"}

response_data = requests.get(product_url, headers=req_headers, cookies=cookies, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

you can get the product data from response text.
for getting reviews you can use this url :

```
host = "lazada.sg" // you can use any region here
"https://my.{}/pdp/review/getReviewList?itemId={}&pageSize=100&filter=0&sort=1&pageNo={}".format(host,item_id,page_no)
```

if you want to use selenium you need to set proxy in selenium